# Xcode commandline building with dependent project

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, build

I'm building a iOS application that uses a library that I've built using [jverkoey's framework structure](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework).  All is well and good, until I try to let my CI environment (Jenkins) build my project.  Jenkins builds using the commandline and when it does so my dependent framework gets built in it's own build directory, and when my main application builds in it's own directory it can't find the framework.

As a test I copied the output from my dependent frameworks build directory into the main apps build directory and re-ran my commandline build and everything works fine.  So what I think I have to do is update my Jenkins build scripts to be able to move the dependent build output before building the main app, or change them to all build in the same directory as XCode does from the IDE with it's DerivedData directory.

The question is, how?  I'm no expert when it comes to building from the commandline and I could really use some help here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out.  Just incase anyone else has a similar problem you can set the SYMROOT setting to whatever directory you want when running xcodebuild.

`xcodebuild -target MyTarget SYMROOT=/Build/MyProj/Sym.root`

Comment: just to be clear:
'SYMROOT=Build/xxx' will still create a seperate dir inside each project, but the name of that dir will be "Build/xxx"
'SYMROOT=/Build/xxx' (with full path notation) will create all build products under "/Build/xxx".

You'll need to use the full path notation.